# Variables in if condition scope

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, block, scoping

There's not much about this argument on this community so I thought to drop this question.

I have this piece of code used for validating `$params['full_name']`:

```
$params = ["full_name"=>"John Doe"];
$full_name = $flag ? null : ( ( $tmp_name = trim(strip_tags((string)@$params['full_name']))
                            &&  (strlen($tmp_name) > 3 && strlen($tmp_name) < 30)
            ) ? $tmp_name : out('The full name must be 3-30 characters', 'Invalid full name'));
```

Despite of `$params['full_name"]` being populated correctly, I get a run-time error:

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: tmp_name
```

Why is this happening? Am I just missing the theory of scoping inside `if` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code isn't very readable or maintainable.  PHP 7 has IFFY's so I would suggest rewriting it in this way:

```
$full_name = $flag 
    ? null 
    : (function($params) {
         $tmp_name = trim(strip_tags((string)@$params['full_name']));
         return (strlen($tmp_name) > 3 and strlen($tmp_name) < 30)
           ? $tmp_name 
           : out('The full name must be 3-30 characters', 'Invalid full name');
       })($params);
```

Your code can be made to work.  The issue is the precedence of operations.  The `&&` operator has a higher precedence than the assignment operator, thus in this circumstance the assignment to $tmp_name is not done prior to the evaluation of the logical `&&`.  This is illustrated in [the operators chart](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

To force the assignment to occur first you have to wrap the assignment in an additional set of parens.

Personally speaking, I don't like to have to code around issues like this if I don't have to, but since you wanted an explanation here's a fixed version:

```
$full_name = $flag ? null : ((($tmp_name = trim(strip_tags((string)@$params['full_name'])))
                            &&  (strlen($tmp_name) > 3 && strlen($tmp_name) < 30)) 
                            ? $tmp_name 
                            : out('The full name must be 3-30 characters', 'Invalid full name'));
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. What does IFFY stand for? 

The code isn't very maintainable because it doesn't need to as it will be a forever static validation one-liner. 

The function within which my line runs in, is around ~600 lines of code and squeezing it is essential for me.

Sadly your reply doesn't really answer my question, which is about getting more insights into how the scoping works inside the IFs. I am completely aware of your solution and I want to ditch it for the above mentioned reasons.

Comment: iffy = iffe = Immediately Invoked Function Expression.  I find your reply pretty curious. I took your exact code and did absolutely nothing to it other than to indent it differently and wrap the portion that doesn't work in the iffe.  It's not any longer than your original code.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm forced to stick to this solution, even though I'd prefer not to as I'm trying avoid the anonymous functions as much as I can. Besides the alternative, may you give me some insights about why my solution does not work? Maybe edit your question and I'l gladly accept it

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation and a solution to make your original code work, even though it's extremely hard to read and understand.

Comment: And finally I got my answer! I was looking forward to eliminating: 1) anonymous functions 2) "and" operators

Answer (score 2):

It's the order of the lazy evaluation that's causing the issue not the scope. If you change your `&&` to `and` the order will be reversed in your case and your code will run fine.

Basically the right side of your `&&` is taking precedence over the left side, due to the assignment operator on the left and so the variable doesn't exist when the right side is evaluated. Using `and` will make the left side evaluate first since it gets lower precedence than the assignment operator thus eliminating the problem.

As an aside. You don't have an `if` statement anywhere in your code. What you have is a ternary expression.

Comment: Your fix is correct, but not for the reason you state, as I interpreted your explanation.  `&&` and `and` both have the same associativity.  The reason the original code doesn't evaluate is that the assignment operator has a lower precedence than the `and` operator.  This allows the assignment to occur prior to the evaluation of the block following.  Perhaps this is what you meant, but your description is misleading in my opinion.

Comment: Still got an upvote, but I think you should clarify why it works.  `&&` has a higher precedence than assignment whereas `and` has a lower precedence.

Comment: That's fair. I can make it more clear in my explanation.